# re.findall only matches the first word from the compiled list in python 3.6

Tags: regex, python-3.x, regex-lookarounds

I have a list of city names and i am trying to match the names in a given string using python. 
for example
my string -> '142 franc drive apt 125 Antelope Creek North Dakota' 
where 'Antelope Creek' = city name(from the Dataframe city column) also, there is a city called as 'Antelope' and 'Antelope Lake'

I am using re.findall method to find all matches. after executing the following re.findall(re.compiled city list, my string). it gives me an output of only 'Antelope' instead of {'Antelope'} {'Antelope Creek'} and {'Antelope Lake'}. Also, if i remove 'Antelope' from the compiled list. It outputs as {'Antelope Creek'} and not {'Antelope Creek'} and {'Antelope Lake'}. Seems like findall matches only the first word. kindly suggest me any solution to find all matches using re.findall. I will attach my code below.

```
my string - '142 franc drive apt 125 Antelope Creek North Dakota' 
pattern = r'\b({0})\b'.format('|'.join(All_city_names.tolist()))
p = re.compile(pattern)
all_values = p.findall(my string)
cities = [tuple(j for j in i if j)[-1] for i in all_values] (%as it is a tuple format)
```

Comment: You can't parse addresses without knowing the full scope of it's variable form. Better contact the US Post Office website for guidance.

Comment: Thank you for the information.But my project task is to only find city and state together. I am building a data-set for states and subsequent cities to parse state and cities from a whole address string

Answer (score 0):

A regex pattern containing `|` will go from left to right and stop as soon as it matches a pattern, ignoring the rest. If you would like to match all cities in your list you would have to match them all individually.

**A simple partial non-regex solution**

```
all_values = [city for city in All_city_names.tolist() if city in my_string]
```

**A slightly longer regex solution**

```
all_values = [city for city in All_city_names.tolist() if re.search(r'\b' + re.escape(city) + r'\b', my_string)]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It helped.

Comment: Glad to be of help!

Answer (score 0):

Regex themselves are executed from left to right.

That means if you have a list in a group of alternations, the first alternation
that matches will cause the engine to move past the group of alternations and
continue to try to match the remainder of the regex.

If your list produces a regex like this `\b(Antelope|Antelope Creek|Antelope Lake)\b`

you can see that only ***`Antelope`*** will ever be given the oppurtunity to match.

To get around this you have to ***sort*** the list in *'descending order'* before the regex
is constructed.

Doing that would produce the following regex:

`\b(Antelope Lake|Antelope Creek|Antelope)\b`

Since the longest (sorted) substrings are at the beginning, the engine now has a chance to match other alternations.